# How to manually create a html link to another store view in CMS content?

Tags: cms, store-view, link

I need to insert a link to CMS content that will point to the same site's different store view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing this:

1. Encode url where you want to point the link to with Base64 by using some online tool and copy the encoded string.
2. The final url you can use in HTML link is going to be like this: https://www.yourdomain.com/stores/store/redirect/___store/DESTINATIONSTOREVIEWCODE/___from_store/SOURCESTOREVIEWCODE/uenc/THE_COPIED_BASE64_ENCODED_STRIN

Insert your source and destination store view codes to that url and also paste the Base64 string at the end.

Put this into link href and it should work and clicking link should now change the store view.